# How can I Map from XML HREF+Text to Word Document Hyperlink?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I Have a simple XML file e.g.:

```xml
 <root>
    <some_link_href>http://www.microsoft.com/</some_link_href>
    <some_link_text>goto microsoft site</some_link_text>
 </root>
```

I have setup XmlMapping, but I can't seem to get a Hyperlink.
I tried using richTextControl and and providing RTF text
(e.g. '{\rtf1\pc some \b BOLD \b0 text}') but it just shown the raw RTF.

> Note: even though I'd like to have a Text with HREF, I can settle for clickable URI

**Is there any other control? other good methods to use?**

also posted @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/720964/place-link-on-winword-from-xmlmapping.html

Comment: You can't use XML mapping for that. Content controls can only be mapped to a single node, so your link ref and link text would have to be mapped to separate controls. You will need to write code to read the xml and then use the values you have extracted to [add a hyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlinks.add)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I'd hate you to be right, though from my fruitless attempts I'm afraid you are! that's a bummer, it seems as a common use-case :(